# EC2 instance not reachable by web deploy

Tags: iis, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, deployment

I'm followed directions here: [how-to-install-webdeploy-on-windows-server-2012](http://www.orcsweb.com/blog/gabe/how-to-install-webdeploy-on-windows-server-2012/) on a server 2012 EC2 instance. Then I followed directions here: [how-to-use-web-deploy-visual-studio-to-importexport-iis8-sites](http://www.orcsweb.com/blog/gabe/how-to-use-web-deploy-visual-studio-to-importexport-iis8-sites/) but VS errors out saying "ERROR DESTINATION NOT REACHABLE" when validating the connection. Is there an additional security setting for EC2 instances?

Answer (score 2):

I had to open up port 8172 on the security group for the instance.